# How do I configure my system so that Windows Python 2.7 CGI scripts see user-defined packages?

Tags: python, windows, apache, cgi

I have a Python script that uses some of my own packages in my own library which is stored in a non-standard folder: k:\lib. When running the script from the command-line the interpreter can find my packages because I have set the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

However, when running the script as a CGI script, the environment variable does not seem to be read, so my question is what can I do about this?

One solution I read was to put

```
import sys
sys.path.append( 'k:\\lib' )
```

at the top of my script but this doesn't work - the next line in my script is

```
import site_consts
```

where site_consts is in k:\lib but I get the error message "no module named site_consts".

Not sure if this is Python problem or a Windows or an Apache one.

Comment: It's a pity you deleted your latest question; had you been a bit more patient I could have shown you that for CGI programs, you *always* need to encode `unicode` values; there are good ways of doing that and even make `print` behave for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `name.pth` file to one of the four directories described [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#module-site) in the documentation.